# how to pass input message text as a parameter with other exe

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I want a bat script, which is required input message text as a parameter, append with other exe.

I have a exe. Client require launch this exe with dynamic parameter. This dynamic parameter should type end user (input message).

Please help me..

suppose: i have abcd.exe and parameter is "APACDBPRD1", It should launch "abcd.exe APACDBPRD1"

Answer (score 0):

in the exe file..

```
@command /p %1
```

And in the command line..

```
abcd.exe APACDBPRD1
```

If you have 2 params to pass 
in the exe file..

```
@command /p %1   /r %2
```

And in the command line..

```
abcd.exe APACDBPRD1 LAKGJSJD2
```

Comment: this is dynamic parameter.  can't implement above script.

Answer (score 0):

This is a work for [SystemCommandTasklet](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/SystemCommandTasklet.html)

> Tasklet that executes a system command. The system command is executed
>   asynchronously using injected setTaskExecutor(TaskExecutor) - timeout
>   value is required to be set, so that the batch job does not hang
>   forever if the external process hangs. Tasklet periodically checks for
>   termination status (i.e. setCommand(String) finished its execution or
>   setTimeout(long) expired or job was interrupted). The check interval
>   is given by setTerminationCheckInterval(long). When job interrupt is
>   detected tasklet's execution is terminated immediately by throwing
>   JobInterruptedException. setInterruptOnCancel(boolean) specifies
>   whether the tasklet should attempt to interrupt the thread that
>   executes the system command if it is still running when tasklet exits
>   (abnormally).

Passing parameter must be done tagging step with `scope="step"` and use late-binding